# How to verify a mailto link behind a button using Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: selenium, web-scraping, button, webdriver, mailto

There is a `Contact Us` button in a website which when clicked opens up the default mail client using the mailto link attached to it through Javascript.

How can I verify the mailto link tagged to the button using Selenium WebDriver?

Comment: The href will contain "mailto: email@emailhost.com".  It's up to the browser what to do with that when clicked.  It's probably enough to just check that it contains the proper href.

Comment: Please share a link to that page

Comment: @pcalkins it's set using javascript. there's no href in the html.

Comment: I also have this problem. A solution is to register a mailto protocol handler (e.g. to gmail) and assert that the link opens a gmail tab. Registering the handler is the tricky part (I'm still looking..).